# GraphQL error update mutation "Resolve function for \"User.id\" returned undefined"

Tags: undefined, graphql, resolve, mutation

I am a newbie to GraphQL and trying to write an update mutation.  However, I am receiving Resolve function for \"User.id\" returned undefined" error although the database is actually got updated.

What am I doing wrong?

**userSchema.js:**

```html
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import SqlHelper from '../helpers/sqlhelper';

const config = require('../../config');

const sequelizer = new SqlHelper(config).Init();


const createUser = sequelizer.define(
  'createUser',
  {
    ...
    }
);
const updateUser = sequelizer.define(
  'updateUser',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      field: 'Id',
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    username: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      field: 'Username',
      allowNull: true,
    },    
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      field: 'Email',
      allowNull: true,
    },
    firstname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      field: 'FirstName',
      allowNull: true,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      field: 'LastName',
      allowNull: true,
    },
   ....
  },
  {
    // define the table's name
    tableName: 'Users',
  },
);

module.exports = User;
```

**UserResolver.js:**

```html
import User from '../dbschemas/user';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

export default {
  
  Mutation: {
    createUser: async (obj, args) =>
      (await User.create(args)),
    updateUser: async (obj, args) =>
      (await User.update(args,
        {
          where: {
            id: args.id,
          },
          returning: true
        }))

  }
};
```

Although calling updateUser from GraphiQL updates the records (in db), it results in a "Resolve function for \"User.id\" returned undefined" error:

```html
mutation{
  updateUser(id: "2ecd38ca-cf12-4e79-ac93-e922f24af9e3", 
    username: "newUserTesting",  
    email: "testemail@yahoo.com",     
    lastname: "TestUserLName", 
    firstname: "fname1") {
   id
  } 
}
```

```html
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Resolve function for \"User.id\" returned undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 16,
          "column": 4
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "updateUser",
        "id"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What happens if you return another field from a mutation other than `id`? Perhaps try `firstname` instead.

Comment: same error: "Resolve function for \"User.firstname\" returned undefined"

Answer (score 1):

The issue is clear, your resolver does not return an object containing `id`.
[The docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update) say that `Model.update` returns an array in which the 2nd element is the affected row.
Hence, your resolver should look like:

```
async updateUser(obj, args) {
  const resultArray = await User.update( ... )
  return resultArray[1]
}
```

... To be replaced by whatever you need.

Comment: added console.log('resultArray', resultArray);

produces: resultArray[ undefined, 1 ] 

And I get the same error as before!

Comment: Also, there is another Update in the docs: public update(updates: Object, options: Object): Promise<this>

Comment: Still have `returning: true` ? You still have the error because when are returning `1`which does not have a property `id`

Comment: If returning: true is removed,  console.log('resultArray', resultArray); outputs: resultArray[  1 ] .  1 is the number of records, it does not return the both elements in the array. If I update 7 records, it logs resultArray[  7 ] . If I add returning: true back, it logs esultArray[ undefined, 7 ] . The documentation says that the first element in the array is the affectedCount, and the second is affectedRows... seems to be vise versa not to metion that affectedRows are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, update does NOT return affected rows for MSSQL,  only the number of records affected.

This is true only for postgres when returning: true:

```
public static update(values: Object, options: Object): Promise<Array<affectedCount, affectedRows>>
```

Setting returning: true (for MSSQL) returns undefined (and order of params in the array is not even in the right order... i.e. first affectedRows -> undefined, then affectedCount ->num of affected rows.)

Tho get an object back you would need to do something like this:

```
Mutation: {
createUser: async (obj, args) =>
  (await User.create(args.user)),
updateUser: async (obj, args, context, info) =>{        
  let user = args.user;
  let response = await User.update(user,
      {
        where: {
          [Op.or]: [{ email: user.email }, { id: user.id }, { username: user.username }, { lastname: user.lastname}]
        },
        //returning: true //not working... only for postgres db :(
      }).then(ret => {   
        console.log('ret', ret);         
        return ret[0];
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error)
      });

  if (response > 0) return user; //return record 

  //return response > 0; //return true
}
```

}